# Get Python Executable Path

Tags: c#, python, windows, executable

How can I:

1. Check if Python is installed on a machine and, if it is, then
2. Get the executable path to it?

Note: I'm fine with it being Python, IronPython, etc... Just anything that I can pass a .py file and have it run it.

I could hard code some paths (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Iron Python... ), but I'd like something more elegant, if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining this registry key works alright:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\open\command
```

If it's not there, then I just ask the user.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not what you're looking for but the Powershell Cmdlet get-command outputs the full executable path. For example:

```
get-command python | ForEach-Object -Process {write-host $_.Definition}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea, but I'll need to do this on each user's computer and installing PowerShell on their computers isn't an option.

Comment: Helped me when I needed to find which python executable PowerShell uses!